# Submitting an Index Sitemap to Bing when the individual sitemaps are hosted on AWS

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, bing-webmaster-tools

Been working on the site map recently and now I want to submit it on Bing Webmaster tools.

The main site map includes several others, each one for a different country.   Like this:

```
sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.gosur.com/sitemaps/afghanistan.xml
</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.gosur.com/sitemaps/albania.xml
</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.gosur.com/sitemaps/algeria.xml
</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.gosur.com/sitemaps/andorra.xml
</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.gosur.com/sitemaps/angola.xml
</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>...
```

Bing told me that there was an error submitting it. Maybe cause its hosted on Amazon?
How can I submit this sitemap to Bing?

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft does support cross domain sitemaps](http://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2008/02/27/microsoft-to-support-cross-domain-sitemaps/) but with a bunch of caveats.

The sitemap can be hosted on a different domain, but only if it is specified in robots.txt and all the URLs in it must point to the current domain.   If you want to submit this set of sitemaps to Bing, you will either have to host them all on your own domain name, or list them individually in your *robots.txt* file:

```
Sitemap: https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.gosur.com/sitemaps/afghanistan.xml
Sitemap: https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.gosur.com/sitemaps/albania.xml
Sitemap: https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.gosur.com/sitemaps/algeria.xml
Sitemap: https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.gosur.com/sitemaps/andorra.xml
Sitemap: https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.gosur.com/sitemaps/angola.xml
...
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Will certainly do that and tell you later how it was.